# install curses .whl package on windows

Tags: python, windows, pip, python-3.5, curses

I want to install curses .whl package so I can use it with pick (https://github.com/wong2/pick) on windows.

```
PS C:\D\Programming\Python> python --version
Python 3.5.2 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.

PS C:\D\Programming\Python> pip.exe install .\curses-2.2-cp35-none-win32.whl
curses-2.2-cp35-none-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Any ideea why ?

Answer (score 3):

It worked with curses-2.2-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl (http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#curses)

Comment: For future viewers, this exact `.whl` package might not work with your system. There are a list of packages mentioned in the link above. Try downloading all and `python -m pip install <package_name>` all of them.